# How to show the latest bzr revision number of a branch

Tags: bazaar, awk

I'd like to get the latest revision number of a given bzr branch on the console, and I'm wondering if there is any bzr command that does that for me.

For now, I'm thinking of just running `bzr log -r-1 | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}'` and I'm just thinking if there is a more proper way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be achieved by `bzr revno`

See http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-guide/version_info.html for more information.